# Time complexity of recursive algorithms with branches of different complexity

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I have the algorithm

```
def alg(a):
    if a == 0:
        return 1
    elif a % 2 == 1:
        return alg(a - 1)
    else:
        return alg(a / 2)
```

and am not certain what its complexity is. One branch has complexity of O(N) and the other O(log(N)).

Do you in this case say that the algorithm has complexity of O(N) since that is the worse case or is the complexity something completely different in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would normally shrug your shoulders and say "Yup, this branch has O(x), and so it's at least that bad."

But if we're a little clever we can see that your algorithm has a base case which is O(1) and then two other cases: even and odd.

If even, the problem size is cut in half.

If odd the problem size is decremented by 1 before being cut in half (as a result of being decremented by 1).

Worst case scenario is that after every even number cut in half is an odd number, but that's still pretty good as that reduces to `O(log(n))`.